# Cannot install old versions of gcc

Tags: gcc, g++

I need gcc-6 and g++-6 to compile a specific program (related with CUDA), I am tried to follow [these](https://gist.github.com/zuyu/7d5682a5c75282c596449758d21db5ed) instructions but for some reasons I get the following:

```
> sudo apt-get install gcc-6 g++-6 -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gcc-6 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package g++-6 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gcc-6' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'g++-6' has no installation candidate
```

Is there an easy way to install these kind of versions of gcc and g++?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instructions you use should be in between the version you use and the last LTS. Those are from 3 years ago so, as you see, not likely to do what you want. I would suggest installing gcc-6 from source in /opt/ and then create a link to the executable.

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind, any suggestion or steps to do it?

Comment: wellll.. it is not easy. I was looking for a link https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC is the best I could find but it is not as simple as I would hope it to be. Hopefully someone will show up with a working method :)

Comment: Nope :) but come to think of it I have a better solution: install Ubuntu 18.04 in a VM that has gcc6 and use that for this and not your 20.04 system. Seems less hassle and you can burn the VM when you do not need it anymore.